# How to store a reference to a Collection in a Model in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

When creating new collection (Choices) I want to set a property on it (ex: _question) which links back to the containing Model (MultipleChoiceQuestion)

Comment: In my opinion the title should be "How to store reference to Collection in Model in Backbone.js".

I think your own answer is correct and shows a proper way to do this.

Comment: Good point @try-catch-finally. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that although my 1st answer technically works, there's a plugin that makes care of storing collections in models (and creating appropriate One->Many, One->One and Many->One relationships

https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

Using that plugin you store the parent question as an ATTRIBUTE

```
m.MultipleChoiceQuestion = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'choices', //says to store the collection in the choices attribute
        relatedModel: m.Choice, //knows we are talking about the choices models
        includeInJSON: true, //when we do toJSON() on the Question we want to show serialize the choices fully
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'question', //in the CHOICE object there will be an attribute called question which contains a reference to the question 
            includeInJSON: false //when we do .toJSON on a CHOICE we don't want to show the question object (or maybe we want to show the ID property in which case we set it to "id")
        }
    }],
    coolFunction: function () {
        this.get('choices').each(function(choice){
            choice.doSomethingChoicey();
        });
    }
});
```

So now if we are in the choices model we can fully reference anything in the parent question:

```
m.Choice = m.RelationalModel.extend({
    coolFunction: function(){
        this.get('question').doSomemethingQuestiony();
        var question_numer = this.get('question').get('question_number');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This took me quite a bit of time to figure out, so in case somebody in the future has this problems...here's the code I ended up writing.

I discovered, unlike Model, Collection's initialize() function accepts 2 parameters. The first is `models` (which is a list of models you can initialize the collection with). The second is `options` (what you want). For a while my Collection started out with 1 model inside and I couldn't figure out why. Turns out I was passing my `options` into the `models` field.

THE CONTAINING MODEL:

```
m.MultipleChoiceQuestion = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //NULL as first parameter because we don't want models
        this.choices = new c.Choices(null, { 
            _question: this //this is referring to current question
        }); //choices Collection is this
    }
});
```

THE COLLECTION

```
c.Choices = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options){
        this._question = options._question;
    },
    model: m.Choice
});
```